# How to add button to side of container

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am creating UI of account page with order list. I need to add arrow button to right side of basket widget. I created column with 3 rows, but i don't know how to add arrow button to right side.

[image]

```
class BasketItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const BasketItem({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
      height: 95,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('#462', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey[700]),),
              Text('Processing', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey[700]),),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('299.99', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 18),),
              Text('2023-09-21', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey[700]),),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('1 item', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey[700]),),
              Text('09:31 PM', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey[700]),),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Output is here]
You can try card and columns for this example. This is the basic way, you can try learnin some another ways. You can change font sizes and spacing between columns.

```
Card(
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                       Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("#462"),
                    SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
                    Text("2392"),
                    SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
                    Text("1 items"),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("Processing"),
                    SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
                    Text("2020-05-19"),
                    SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
                    Text("9:34 PM"),
                  ],
                ),
                        Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with the help of [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw1rqkBhCTARIsAAHz7K2ZnHsKUtuJPi-7VChmewKKINgGHmG6meEsYPjPUb2pYUTeTa6TrzUaAutvEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) Widget..

**Sudo code**

```
         ListTile(
            title: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('John Doe'),
                Text('john.doe@example.com'),
              ],
            ),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            onTap: () {
              // HANDLE ON TAP 
            },
          ),
```

**`title:`** can be take any `Widget` as a child. You can replace your existing  code here..